# Symfony same @groups between two table with ManyToMany relations

Tags: symfony, orm, many-to-many, entity, api-platform.com

I want to have the same @groups between  two table with ManyToMany relations: When i get on API Platform .../api/tags/1, I recieve only that without "tag".

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "A ce monde que tu fais"
}
```

App\Entity\Song

```php
    /**
     * @Groups({"song:read", "song:write"})
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Tag::class, inversedBy="songs", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(
     *  name="song_tag",
     *  joinColumns={
     *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="song_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *  },
     *  inverseJoinColumns={
     *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *  })
     * 
     */
    private $tags;
```

App\Entity\Tag

```php
    /**
     * @Groups({"song:read", "song:write"})
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Song::class, mappedBy="tags")
     */
    private $songs;
```

I think it's the join table between the two, it doesn't have a defined group. Can you help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by:

> When i get on API Platform .../api/tags/1, I recieve only that without "tag".

From what I understand, your problem is likely the result of missing [normalization context](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/#normalization) configuration. `Tag` endpoints, such as `/api/tags/1`, are not configured to apply the `song:read` and `song:write` serialization groups by default, resulting in these `Tag` fields being excluded in the response payload.

Consider adding `song:read` and `song:write` as default serialization groups for the `Tag` endpoints. Or preferably, specify `tag:read` and `tag:write` serialization groups and add them to the `Song` serialization groups. A simple example:

```php
<?php declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ApiResource(
 *      itemOperations={
 *          "get"={
 *              "normalization_context"={
 *                  "groups"={
 *                      "song:read",
 *                  },
 *              },
 *          },
 *      },
 * )
 */
class Song
{
    /**
     * @Groups({
     *     "song:read",
     *     "tag:read",
     * })
     */
    private Collection $tags;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ApiResource(
 *      itemOperations={
 *          "get"={
 *              "normalization_context"={
 *                  "groups"={
 *                      "tag:read",
 *                  },
 *              },
 *          },
 *      },
 * )
 */
class Tag
{
    /**
     * @Groups({
     *     "tag:read",
     *     "song:read",
     * })
     */
    private Collection $songs;
}
```

PS: Consider that the above example establishes a [circular reference](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#handling-circular-references).

Comment: by

> When i get on API Platform .../api/tags/1, I recieve only that without "tag".

I mean that when I make a request, I want to get the tags back. I've already tried it and it works with the oneToMany and the oneToOne but not for the ManyToMany.

I want 

``` json
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "world",
  "category": {"id":54, "name":"hello"},
  "tags": [{"id":12, "name":"city"}, {...}]
}
```
and I haven't tags


I think it's really the join table between the two, it doesn't have a defined group because symfony did not create an entity and therefore no group...

Answer (score 0):

by

> When i get on API Platform .../api/tags/1, I recieve only that without "tag".

I mean that when I make a request, I want to get the tags back. I've already tried it and it works with the oneToMany and the oneToOne but not for the ManyToMany.

I want

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "world",
  "category": {"id":54, "name":"hello"},
  "tags": [{"id":12, "name":"city"}, {...}]
}
```

and I have only

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "world",
  "category": {"id":54, "name":"hello"},
}
```

I think it's really the join table between the two, it doesn't have a defined group because symfony did not create an entity and therefore no group...